# .env file shows errors(red underlines) in vscode - it works fine though

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I'm having this project structure:

[image]

Although the file works correctly but it shows errors(red underlines) in VSCODE.

Why does this happen and how can we solve this?

Comment: It's probably because it doesn't match the typical .env file format that VS Code expects. In the lower right portion of VS Code, in the status bar, what does it show as the type of file?

Comment: Good point, it says typescript (confused)

Comment: I figured it out, we can install the dotenv extension and it adds the file association for this type of file and then we can change it in bottom right bar.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to handle it. Both work properly.

**First (Suppressing Error) -**

1. Changing Language Mode to IGNORE, as shown below

[image: Language Mode IGNORE]

**Second (Appropriate) -**

1. Download DotENV extension from Visual studio code
2. Change the language mode to Environment Variables

[image: Language Mode Environment Variables]